# Apache Nifi custom processor and custom controller service packaging structure

Tags: apache-nifi

I saw this example for Apache NiFi (https://medium.com/hashmapinc/creating-custom-processors-and-controllers-in-apache-nifi-e14148740ea) but still can't get my head around on how to implement packaging structure for custom processors and controller service.

My goal is to create a custom controller service to be used my multiple custom processors. How should my maven structure look like?

- Should I create a nar for controller service?
- Should I include controller service dependency in all my custom processors?
- Should I be copying both the CS nar and CP nars to NiFi /lib directory?

**Example**: 
Controller Service - CS1
Custom Processor 1 - CP1
Custom Processor 2 - CP2

I want CS1 to be used in both CP1 and CP2. If possible please share maven structure for this scenario and how it works. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

The most flexible setup would be the one shown here:

https://github.com/bbende/nifi-dependency-example

Comment: The above setup generates 3 nars : 
nifi-example-service-nar,
nifi-example-service-api-nar,
nifi-example-processors-nar. 

Which of these nars should we use it in NiFi lib directory?

Comment: All of three of them

Comment: Ok, Thanks! Let me try it out.